# performance degradation on mongodb 3.2.10

Tags: mongodb

server :ubuntu 16.04 
database :mongodb 3.2.10 
configuration (replica set 3 nodes) 
engine WiredTiger 
we are having performance related to querying , the query run time degraded over the time and it does not seem to be related to load as no users accessing the node , the current fix is by restarting the mongo instance. i had the same issue on 3.2.9 version , it seems to keep happening on 3.2.10 as well the degradation is happening on all nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Few tips to verify performance issues in MongoDB

1. In MongoDB Profiler you can check the slow running queries.
    You can try indexing the documents (use inputs from above step)
2. Since the instances are replicated please revisit the write concern part https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-write-concern/
3. can you check whether mongodb in-memory implementation can help https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/inmemory/
4. You can see few important tips here - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/analyzing-mongodb-performance/

Comment: option 1 and 2 are not applicable to the case and the read operation (1 read command )returns in less than 1 second most of the time .

Comment: option 3 is not applicable as well not enterprise version . the read command is already tuned , is there a tool that can help identify what the read operation is waiting on ?

Comment: Please visit the URL for different administrator level options to monitor performance of mongoDB. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/monitoring/